# python into to char to string coversion

Tags: python, string, char, type-conversion

I am taking a cryptography course and I managed to convert a string of hex values to their int equivalents. I know want to convert these to their char equivalent using the chr(x) function that takes a number from 0-255 and returns the corresponding ASCII value. I want to then take all these and show them as one string.

Here is some simple code:

```
x = [49, 21, 92, 196, 78, 238, 234, 170, 168, 139, 181, 95, 248, 138, 170, 175, 249, 145, 23, 116, 65, 20, 69, 91, 191, 244, 67, 62, 225, 23, 120, 132, 75, 184, 143, 250, 160, 0, 13, 220, 199, 113, 29, 216, 136, 133, 90, 168, 128, 4, 78, 229, 94, 238, 233, 159, 250, 164, 64, 11, 177, 22, 99, 52, 73, 156, 193, 20, 70, 111, 251, 183, 119, 120, 140, 205, 223, 242, 45, 211, 58, 175, 255, 240, 2, 33, 29, 223, 255, 255, 245, 91, 180, 64, 3, 59, 181, 81, 16, 13, 208, 13, 208, 4, 69, 85, 84, 70, 104, 138, 174, 235, 185, 152, 134, 98, 34, 43, 177, 19, 55, 125, 218, 174, 232, 133, 87, 117, 85, 83, 60, 204, 205, 216, 136, 136, 131, 58, 167, 123, 188, 195, 55, 117, 82, 32, 14, 224, 6, 110, 229, 81, 21, 93, 210, 34, 44, 201, 149, 84, 78, 235, 186, 165, 80, 2, 37, 91, 184, 140, 204, 197, 87, 126, 238, 229, 89, 148, 65, 24, 140, 206, 231, 125, 220, 198, 107, 188, 196, 65, 21, 85, 86, 107, 189, 219, 179, 54, 107, 187, 188, 202, 163, 62, 232, 135, 119, 116, 67, 48, 1, 31, 251, 188, 202, 170, 163, 59, 184, 131, 59, 178, 34, 32, 8, 128, 9, 149, 86, 96, 9, 152, 135, 120, 129, 21, 95, 246, 101, 82, 40, 134, 103, 118, 100, 71, 112, 3, 61, 222, 224, 15, 243, 61, 213, 82, 36, 68, 64, 0, 10, 161, 25, 155, 177, 21, 89, 150, 97, 16, 11, 177, 17, 30, 239, 243, 62]

result = ""
for i in x:
    print chr(i)
    result = result + chr(i)
print result
```

What puzzles me is that when I do "print chr(i)" I get the character '1' which is ASCII for 42. However as I append this to the "result" string it seems to change. When I then print the "result" in the final line the first character of my string is not a '1'.

Any ideas? Busting my head for 2 days now until i managed to trace the issue with my crypto code to these few lines.

Cheers

Comment: try this way  print ''.join(map(chr, x))

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's the darnest thing. The code you sent does exactly the same as mine. Still the first character is not a '1'. Try it if you can, you'll see for yourself :/

Comment: Try this first is '1' :  x = [49,50]; print ';'.join(map(chr, x))

Comment: That's strange, when I run your code, I get the first character to be `1`. Maybe you are misreading? Try printing `result[0]` and see what the output is.

Comment: chr(49) === '1' and chr(42) === '*'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct. The output just gets mangled because, in the encoding that’s being used, some of the subsequent characters (i.e. *after* the `1`) are control characters, which cause previously written output to be overwritten, when printed to the terminal.

You can easily verify this by looking that there are control characters in your string:

```
import curses.ascii

num_ctrl = len(filter(curses.ascii.iscntrl, result))
# num_ctrl = 41
```

Furthermore, you can examine *which* control characters you’re dealing with, by using the following snippet:

```
control_chars = [curses.ascii.controlnames[ord(x)] for x in result if curses.ascii.isctrl(x)]
# control_chars = ['NAK', 'ETB', …]
```

You can look up the meaning of those [in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.ascii.html). In particular, note that your string contains the <kbd>BS</kbd> control sequence, which corresponds to a backspace.

And lastly, you can filter out control characters and just print the remainder:

```
print ''.join([x for x in result if not curses.ascii.isctrl(x)])
# 1\�N�ꪨ��_��tAE[��C>�x�K�����q؈�Z��N�^�…
```

Comment: thanks Konrad for the detailed response and the code snippets. Makes perfect sense! I will proceed with your instructions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generator expression, then `join` to create a single string

```
>>> ''.join(chr(i) for i in x)
'1\x15\\ÄNîêª¨\x8bµ_ø\x8aª¯ù\x91\x17tA\x14E[¿ôC>á\x17x\x84K¸\x8fú\xa0\x00\rÜÇq\x1dØ\x88\x85Z¨\x80\x04Nå^îé\x9fú¤@\x0b±\x16c4I\x9cÁ\x14Foû·wx\x8cÍßò-Ó:¯ÿð\x02!\x1dßÿÿõ[´@\x03;µQ\x10\rÐ\rÐ\x04EUTFh\x8a®ë¹\x98\x86b"+±\x137}Ú®è\x85WuUS<ÌÍØ\x88\x88\x83:§{¼Ã7uR \x0eà\x06nåQ\x15]Ò",É\x95TNëº¥P\x02%[¸\x8cÌÅW~îåY\x94A\x18\x8cÎç}ÜÆk¼ÄA\x15UVk½Û³6k»¼Ê£>è\x87wtC0\x01\x1fû¼Êª£;¸\x83;²" \x08\x80\t\x95V`\t\x98\x87x\x81\x15_öeR(\x86gvdGp\x03=Þà\x0fó=ÕR$D@\x00\n¡\x19\x9b±\x15Y\x96a\x10\x0b±\x11\x1eïó>'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's the darnest thing. The code you sent does exactly the same as mine. Still the first character is not a '1'. Try it if you can, you'll see for yourself :/

Comment: The first character is indeed `1`, why do you think it isn't?

Comment: PO may think that first is 1\x